# Procedure to compare two columns from different tables and make the insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables:

1. PROJECT with fields fld_id (integer), fld_allocated_hours (integer), fld_project_id (integer)
2. TIMESHEET with fields fld_id (integer), fld_allocated_time (integer), fld_project_id (integer)

And I have this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_allocated_time(p_project_id integer, p_allocated_time integer)
  RETURNS void 
  AS
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO dbo.Timesheet(fld_id, fld_project_id,fld_allocated_time)
from
(
  SELECT p.fld_id, p.fld_allocated_hours t.fld_allocated_time
  FROM dbo.Project p
  INNER JOIN dbo.Timesheet t
  ON p.fld_id=t.fld_id
  where t.fld_project_id = p_project_id
)AS Alias
GROUP BY fld_id, fld_allocated_days, fld_allocated_time
having SUM(fld_allocated_time) < fld_allocated_hours;
END;
```

I want to make this procedure:

1. Insert the allocated_time in table Timesheet from parameter fld_project_id
2. Check if the column SUM(fld_allocated_time) from table Timesheet is smaller or equals with fld_allocated_hours from table Project.
3. Make the insertion or error message or exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use IF...ELSE block to check the condition and do appropriate action based on the result of condition. for that you need to store the result of SUM(fld_allocated_time) and fld_allocated_hours into variables and then:

```
IF @sumResult <= @allocatedTime 
BEGIN
--do some stuff
END
ELSE
BEGIN
--do some other stuff
END
```